# (Python Beginner's Help) getch?

Tags: python, getch

I am making a game. I want people to run main.py then they come across a little menu with options. Atm I am getting an error.

So here are the 3 files:

```
ascii.py:

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        ascii
# Purpose:     To create all the ascii art and graphic tools for the game:
#              "you wake up..."
#
# Author:      William Bryant
#
# Created:     15/12/2013
# Copyright:   (c) William 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import time
import os

WOODEN_DOOR = """ ______________________________
/_____/_____/_____/_____/_____/
 ._.                    ._.
 | |                    | |
 |_|   ______   ______  |_|
 |-|  /__1__/  /__2__/  |-|         ___________
 | |                    | |         || ||| ||||
 |_|                    |_|         || ||| ||||
 ._.                    ._.         ||_||| ||||
 | |                    | |        _||_|||_||||_
 |_|   ______           |_|
 |-|  /__3__/           |-|
 | |              /\    | |
 |_|              \/    |_|
 ._.                    ._.                                     _____
 | |                    | |        ____________________________|_____|
 |_|   ______   ______  |_|       | |______________________________| |
 |-|  /__4__/  /__5__/  |-|       | |                              | |
 | |                    | |       |_|                              |_|
 |_|                    |_|                    17615.5 x 2
  ____________________________________________________________________
 /_____/  /_____/__/_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/
 /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/  /_____/"""

#Error message if user executes the wrong file.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("[ERROR]: Do not run this file. Run main.py - this file should not be executed!")
    time.sleep(4)
    exit()

#Clear function
def clear():
    """
    Clears the console screen using the built in commands on a operating
    system (here linux and windows)
    """
    os.system(['clear','cls', "^L"][os.name == 'nt'])

#"Wake up..." title/banner at the start
def ywu_banner(num_of_times):
    """
    Prints You wake up...(the game name) in ascii code big letters into a
    console and clears the screen using the clear function above and reprints
    the message to make the dots at the end appear to be moving.
    """
    print("__     __                         _")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("\ \   / /                        | |")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) | _ _ ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .__(_|_|_)")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("                                                  | |    ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("                                                  |_| ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    clear()

    for foo in range(num_of_times):
        print("__     __                         _")
        print("\ \   / /                        | |")
        print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
        print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
        print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) | _  ")
        print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .__(_|_)")
        print("                                                  | |    ")
        print("                                                  |_| ")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        clear()

        print("__     __                         _")
        print("\ \   / /                        | |")
        print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
        print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
        print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) |  ")
        print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .__(_)")
        print("                                                  | |    ")
        print("                                                  |_| ")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        clear()

        print("__     __                         _")
        print("\ \   / /                        | |")
        print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
        print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
        print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) |  ")
        print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .___/")
        print("                                                  | |    ")
        print("                                                  |_| ")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        clear()

        print("__     __                         _")
        print("\ \   / /                        | |")
        print(" \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ____ _| | _____   _   _ _ __")
        print("  \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | |/ / _ \ | | | | '_ \ ")
        print("   | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| |   <  __/ | |_| | |_) | _ _ ")
        print("   |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_|\_\___|  \__,_| .__(_|_|_)")
        print("                                                  | |    ")
        print("                                                  |_| ")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        clear()

menu_start = """
 _____________    _____________
|             |  |             |
|   *start*   |  |    exit     |
|_____________|  |_____________|
"""

menu_exit = """
 _____________    _____________
|             |  |             |
|    start    |  |   *exit*    |
|_____________|  |_____________|
  """
```

main.py:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        main.py
# Purpose:     An RPG (Roll playing game) where you wake up in a room and have
#              to figure out text based puzzles to escape.
#              The whole game will be done in a terminal (Shell) and will be
#              completely text and ascii code. This will be the main file.
#
# Author:      William Bryant
#
# Created:     15/12/2013
# Copyright:   (c) William Bryant 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import time
import ascii
import quests
import msvcrt

#The function that starts/restarts the game
def start():
    """
    Calls all the functions to start the game/ restart the game
    """
    ascii.clear()
    #Display a cool banner
    ascii.ywu_banner(2)

    options()
    time.sleep(0.7)
    ascii.clear()

    #Game text.
    game_text()

def init():
    state = "start"
    print(ascii.menu_start)
    move = msvcrt.getch()
    enter = False
    while enter == False:

        move

        if move == b'\r' and state == 'start':
            enter = True
            start()

        elif move == b'\r' and state == 'exit':
            enter = False
            exit()

        elif move == b'K' or move == b'M' and state == "start":
            ascii.clear()
            print(ascii.menu_exit)
            state = "exit"
            move

        elif move == b'K' or move == b'M' and state == "exit":
            ascii.clear()
            print(ascii.menu_start)
            state = "start"



#The text which is the main story line after the banner which gives the player
#A sense of what the setting is about
def game_text():
    """
    Prints out a bit of text 2 lines down and clears the screen every 4 or so
    seconds.
    """
    time.sleep(5)

    print("\n\nYour eyes gentally and gradually, open")
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nYou slowly gather your senses and sit up...")
    time.sleep(4.5)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nYou look around the room, and try to make sense of the")
    print("environment you are in and to your surprise, you realise your in some")
    print("sort of a prison cell!")
    time.sleep(12.5)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nYou place your hand on the wall...")
    time.sleep(3)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\n... It feels like some sort of metal.")
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print('\n\n"How did I get here?", \nYou think to yourself')
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    quests.accept_quest("Find a way out. Do you accept? ")
    time.sleep(10)
    ascii.clear()

    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\nYou see a wooden door next to your bed with 5 buttons and a handel...  ")
    time.sleep(10)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\n\nYou the figure out that it's some sort of combination lock.")
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

    quests.door_lock_quest()
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\nThe door makes a click, you twist the handle anti-clockwise and it slides open")
    time.sleep(4)
    ascii.clear()
    time.sleep(2)

#if the file is the main file then start the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

and quests.py:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        quests
# Purpose:     To contain quests functions for the game "Yoy wake up..."
#
# Author:      William Bryant
#
# Created:     17/12/2013
# Copyright:   (c) William Bryant 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import time
import ascii
import main

#Error message if user executes the wrong file.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("[ERROR]: Do not run this file. Run main.py - this file should not be executed!")
    time.sleep(4)
    exit()

#Helper function for the quests
def accept_quest(name):
    """
    If the player doesn't accept the quest, then the player can't move on. If
    they say yes, then they continue through the script. If they say no, then the init
    function is called from main.py and they get a message.
    """
    answered = False
    while answered is False:
        quest_accept = input("Quest: " + name)
        if quest_accept.upper in ["YES", "ACCEPT"]:
            time.sleep(2)
            print("\nYou accepted the quest")
            answered = True

        elif quest_accept.upper in ["NO", "DECLINE"]:
            answered = True
            time.sleep(2)
            ascii.clear()
            print("\nYou don't live happily ever after and die.")
            time.sleep(5)
            ascii.clear()
            main.init()

        else:
            print("Type yes or no. ")

        time.sleep(4)

#Function for the first quest: do you want to find a way out?

#Function for the second quest: Mmm lets just the combination..
def door_lock_quest():
    """
    If the player answers the right question (35231) then they get to continue,
    if not then they get a 'GAME OVER' message and the init() function from main
    executes and the game restarts
    """
    combination = False
    accept_quest("Combination lock. Do you accept? ")
    while combination is False:
        QUEST_ANSWER2 = input(ascii.WOODEN_DOOR + "\nThe answer may be somewhere in the room, hmmm lets try this combination: ")
        if QUEST_ANSWER2 in ["35231", 35231]:
            combination = True

        elif QUEST_ANSWER2 not in ["35231", 35231]:
            combination = False
            time.sleep(2)
            ascii.clear()
            print("GAME OVER!!!\nYou die of hunger and lack of water the next day because you didn't answer correctly and couldn't escape!!!")
            time.sleep(7)
            ascii.clear()
            main.init()

        time.sleep(4)
```

For some reason. They keys don't work. This is the first time I am using getch(). I kinda understand it but not really.

[Edit]: Oh I must also point out that I am using Python 3

Comment: What error are you getting... ?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/3109055) you could put the information you gave in your 1st line of the question ;-)

Comment: You've posted *far* too much code here. Just post the  relevant lines - the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set

```
move = msvcrt.getch()
```

you set `move` to the *next pressed character*. The line `move` does nothing. Then you keep looping around and using the same character each time. You need to set `move = msvcrt.getch()` *inside* the loop.

There are some good `getch` examples [here](http://effbot.org/librarybook/msvcrt.htm):

```
# File: msvcrt-example-2.py

import msvcrt
import time

print "press SPACE to enter the serial number"

while not msvcrt.kbhit() or msvcrt.getch() != " ":
    # do something else while we're waiting
    print ".",
    time.sleep(0.1)

print

# clear the keyboard buffer
while msvcrt.kbhit():
    msvcrt.getch()

serial = raw_input("enter your serial number: ")

print "serial number is", serial
```